# What is the Probability Space Underlying a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. The position at step $n$ can be described as a Markov chain $(X_n)$. We know that each $X_n$ is a random variable, so its domain is a probability space, so my question is, is that space the heads/tail space {H,T} or the product heads tail space $\Pi_{\mathbb{N}}\{H,T\}$ in which case $X_n$ are the projection to $n$-th component?

If the underlying probability space is the product space, how exactly do we assign probability to the events given each outcome is an infinite sequence of heads and tails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_n$ is the position of the random walk at time $n$ then the underlying probability space is $\prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ ie. the set of $\mathbb Z$-valued sequences.

The trick is to assign a value not to individual sequences but instead to define the probability of events of the form
$$
X_0 = x_0, X_1 = x_1, \ldots, X_N = x_N
$$
for every $N \in \mathbb N$ and every $(x_0, \ldots, x_N) \in \mathbb Z^{N+1}$.

The Kolmogorov extension theorem then tells you that this uniquely defines a probability on $\prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the sequence space $\Pi_{\Bbb N}\{H,T\}$ as the underlying sample space. In this case, for a sample point $\omega =(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots )$ the step taken at time $k$ is
$$
\xi_k(\omega) = \cases{1,&if $\omega_k=H$,\cr -1,&if $\omega_k=T$,\cr}
$$
and the position of the walker after $n$ steps is
$$
X_n(\omega) =\xi_1(\omega)+\cdots+\xi_n(\omega).
$$
A complete assignment of probabilities requires something like the Kolmogorov theorem as noted by Leo in his answer. Simple events an be handled directly; for example,
$$
P(\xi_1=\xi_2=1,\xi_3=-1) =1/8.
$$